# Array of regex return unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my sample of regex implementation

```
const regexes = [/(.*)\.should\.(.*)/gi];
console.log(regexes.map((re) => re.test('This is .should. true')));
console.log(regexes.map((re) => re.test('This is .should. true')));
console.log(regexes.map((re) => re.test('This is .should. true')));
console.log(regexes.map((re) => re.test('This is .should. true')));
```

when I run that code in developer console, it return:

```
[true]
[false]
[true]
[false]
```

why that same string tested by same regex pattern has return difference values. I believe that should return

```
[true]
[true]
[true]
[true]
```